# Create a new item/object in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm attempting to automate the filing of e-receipts into a digital filing application called [Paperless from Mariner Software](https://marinersoftware.com/product/paperless/).

Within the Paperless AppleScript Dictionary, the following is defined for a *receipt* (class/data type):

> ```
> receipt n [inh. library item] : A receipt. 
> elements contained by .
>
> properties 
> merchant (text) : The merchant's name. 
> amount (text) : amount of the receipt (as a string); can include currency symbol 
> tax (text) : tax or VAT of the receipt (as a string); can include currency
> symbol 
> payment method (text) : method of payment 
> category (text) :
> category of receipt 
> notes (text) : notes for the receipt 
> date (date) : date of the receipt 
> custom 1 (text) : custom data 1 
> custom 2 (text) : custom data 2 
> custom 3 (text) : custom data 3 
> file (file) : file reference for the receipt 
>
>
> responds to add.
> ```

In my AppleScript, I try to create a new receipt with the following code:

```
set MerchantID to "Apple -- testing"

tell application "Paperless"
activate
add  receipt with properties {merchant:MerchantID}
end tell
```

However, it fails with the following error:

```
error "Paperless got an error: Can’t make receipt into type library item." number -1700 from receipt to library item
```

What confuses me about the error is that I am attempting to make a receipt which is a class that is inherited from the more general type *library item*.

Can someone explain how to create a new item based on classes defined like this?

Answer (score 3):

`receipt` is an element belonging to some parent object.  As with any instance of an AppleScript element *that has already been created*, it'll typically be referenced either by `index`, e.g.

```
receipt 1 of ...
```

or by `name`, e.g.

```
receipt "MyNamedReceipt" of ...
```

or by `id`, e.g.

```
receipt id "61405882-ee27-4c94-86bb-bcdecc8792ba" of ...
```

My feeling is that the **`add`** command will act on an instance of a `library item` (including `receipt`) that already exists.  If so, then

```
add receipt ...
```

would most likely generate the error you're seeing, because `receipt` is a class name, where **`add`** would be expecting an identifiable element, e.g.

```
add receipt "MyNamedReceipt" ...
```

Going by typical nomenclature in the AppleScript world, **`add`** commands typically get invoked when one wishes to take a pre-existing object from one location and insert/add it to another.  In *`Paperless`*, this might be taking a `receipt` from, say, a folder (or album) of receipts, and adding either a copy of or a reference to (most likely the latter) that receipt to a different folder/album.

The most common way to **create new instances** of an element in the majority of AppleScriptable applications is by way of the **`make`** command (which is part of the standard suite that an application's scripting dictionary is recommended to contain):

> **make** *v* : Make a new object.
>       **make**
>           **new** *type* : The class of the new object.
>           [**at** *location specifier*] : The location at which to insert the object.
>           [**with data** *any*] : The initial data for the object.
>           [**with properties** *record*] : The initial values for properties of the object.
>       → specifier

If *`Paperless`* includes the **`make`** command, try using that.  It would take a form similar to:

```
make new receipt with properties {name:"My Receipt", merchant:"Apple", amount:"$249.99", tax:"$0.00"}
```

You will need to consider which element owns the collection of `receipts` in which you're attempting to create a new one.  If `library item` is a top-level application object, i.e. owned by `application`, then the **`make`** command should not require the `at` parameter (if it does, it can be a generic `at end of receipts`).  However, if `library item` is owned by, say, a `library` class object, then the **`make`** command either needs to occur within `tell` block targeting that `library` element (e.g. `library 1`, or `library "MyLibrary"`); or it needs the `at` parameter to describe where to create the new `receipt`, e.g.

```
tell application "Paperless"
        .
        .
        .
    make new receipt at library 1 of document 1
        .
        .
        .
end tell
```

where, for illustrative purposes, I've pre-supposed that `library items` are contained by `libraries` are contained by `documents` are contained by the `application`.

Comment: This is a really informative answer, though I haven't gotten the problem fixed yet.  As for your suppositions, you are pretty close:  `library` is contained by `application`; `receipts` are contained by `library`.  There is a `documents` class, but it is basically the same as `receipts` with only minor property differences.  There is a generic `library item` class but per the definition it's just an "abstract class to define a receipt or document."  I think one of my issues is how to reference the `library` currently in use.

Comment: If you wish, you can upload the contents of the scripting definition file to a paste bin, e.g. [**paste.ee**](https://paste.ee), as an extra pair of eyes can be useful.  `set the clipboard to (read (path to resource "Paperless.sdef" in bundle app "Paperless") as "utf8")` will hopefully copy the file contents to your clipboard for pasting (unless they've been annoying and named their `.sdef` file something else).  I suppose this will do it also: `printf "$(</Applications/Paperless.app/Contents/Resources/*.sdef)" | pbcopy`. (**PS**. I don't suppose `library 1` does it ?)

Comment: Yeah....`library 1` didn't do it.  It's a *very* short dictionary.  I've created two links... a [PDF on OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AmW50NkbWLGik-tVwW_Bz_o3-5pLZw) and a txt output on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/d92tRf5w).  Thanks for all your assistance.

Comment: Thanks for uploading those.  The `library` element has a `name` property, so I'm assuming you can reference any `library` via that.  Examining what gets returned by `tell app "Paperless" to return every library` and by ``tell app "Paperless" to return the name of every library` will be helpful in getting the correct name, but also in giving you a clue how to get the active library if _Paperless_ allows you to open more than one (if it does, I'm shocked it doesn't allow you to reference by index number, and that might be something to feed back to them).

Comment: Once you have the name of your library, what's the result from `tell app "Paperless" to tell the library named "<library name>" to make new receipt with properties {name:"My Receipt", merchant:"Apple", amount:"$249.99"}` ?